# Integrate $\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2-\cos^2x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> $$\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2-\cos^2x}}dx$$

I have tried many trig identities but it seems that none have made a way to the solution.

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2-\cos^2x}}dx=\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}}dx$$

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2-\cos^2x}}dx=\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2+\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}}}dx=\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\frac{5+\cos 2x}{2}}}dx$$

Answer (score 4):

From the very beginning, let $u = \cos x$.  Then $du = -\sin x \, dx$, and we have

$$ \int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2 - \cos^2 x}} \, dx = -\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{2 - u^2}}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int  \frac { sinx }{ \sqrt { 2-\cos ^{ 2 } x }  } dx=-\int { \frac { d\left( \cos { x }  \right)  }{ \sqrt { 2-\cos ^{ 2 } x }  }  } $$
and substitute $\\ \cos { x } =t$ so  that you will get

> $$\\ -\int { \frac { dt }{ \sqrt { 2-{ t }^{ 2 } }  }  } =-\int { \frac { d\left( \frac { t }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \right)  }{ \sqrt { 1-{ \left( \frac { t }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }  } =\arccos { \left( \frac { t }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \right)  } =\arccos { \left( \frac { \cos { x }  }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \right)  } +C$$

Comment: and then $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}})^2}?$

Comment: arccos? shouldn't it be arcsin?

Comment: @newhere,no it should be arccos

Comment: @newhere $\int \frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\arcsin x+C$, but $-\int \frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\arccos x+C$ (because of the often neglected identity $\arccos x=\frac\pi2-\arcsin x$)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2-\cos^2x}}dx=\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\frac{3 -\cos 2x}{2}}}dx$$
$$3-\cos 2x=t^2$$
$$\sin x dx=\frac{tdt}{2\cos x}$$
$$3-t^2=2\cos^2 x -1$$
$$\cos x=\sqrt{\frac{4-t^2}{2}}$$
$$\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}$$